# Employer states they can withhold your W-2

Tags: united-states, taxes, w2

My new employer states in the employee handbook that any outstanding debt must be paid before they will release your W-2 form, which is required in the United States when filing your taxes. Is this legal?

Comment: 1.No.  2.What does this even mean?

Comment: Please tag a country.

Comment: Assuming USA, the fine for a company not releasing a W2 for an employee is $50.

Comment: And the W2 is an obligation for your employer, not you. If you need information about your pay, there are other ways of getting it.

Comment: How exactly does an employee become in-debt to an employer?

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/86335/my-former-employer-is-withholding-my-w2-in-exchange-for-supposed-damage-fees-wh?rq=1

Comment: @Donald if they pay for 10K in moving expenses but you quit after a month, tbey want you to pay it back.

Comment: ___"Is this legal?"___ --> Go to [law.se].

Comment: a) Please tag a country. b) What do you mean by "outstanding debt"?

Comment: The question isn't clear to me; please see [ask].

Comment: [Being unresponsive to requests for clarification is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive)

Comment: @DanielR.Collins 1. Taking an advance on salary 2. Getting an advance on moving or travel expenses that they never use 3. Using vacation in advance, more than be recovered by withholding from the final paycheck 4. Destroying or failing to return company equipment 5. Company pays for training on the condition that employee pays it back when they quit 6. ...

Comment: @Donald In addition to what DJClayworth said, putting personal expenses on a business credit card or the company accidentally overpaying the employee would also be instances in which the employee owes the company money.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Think you clicked on the wrong username there.

Comment: @BSMP - Overpayment of a salary wouldn't be a "debt" to the company.  If an employee put "business expenses" on a company's business card, provided they were authorized to make those charges, they woudln't be responsible for those charges personally.  I don't think we have enough information to make any conclusions.  This question cannot be answered.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Yes I did. Meant to be a reply to Donald.

Comment: @Donald I'm not making any assumptions, just pointing out additional ways an employee can end up owing their employer money. It doesn't actually matter what the company means by "debt" though, they can't withhold a W2.

Answer (score 3):

Your employer is [legally obligated to give you your W2](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc752) and it [must be correct](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/irs-procedures/w-2-additional-incorrect-lost-non-receipt-omitted/w-2-additional-incorrect-lost-non-receipt-omitted):

> If by the end of February, your Form W-2, Wage and Tax Statement has not been corrected by your employer after you attempted to have your employer or payer issue a corrected form, you can request that an IRS representative initiate a Form W-2 complaint. Call the IRS toll free at 800-829-1040 or make an appointment to visit an [IRS Taxpayer Assistance Center (TAC)](https://www.irs.gov/help/contact-your-local-irs-office).